# How to parse nested JSON in snowflake and extracting a particular piece of information?

Tags: json, multidimensional-array, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am very new to snowflake and previously have worked in Teradata SQL. I am trying to retrieve information from a column in a snowflake table, whose values are in JSON and look like below:

```
{
  "depositsDMPResponseVO": {
    "depositsApplicationRsnsVO": {
      "applicationID": "YYYYYYY",
      "applicationRefNbr": "XXXXXXXXX",
      "depositsStrategyOutputVOs": [
        {
          "appDescnTms": "2020-08-18T08:07:00Z",
          "depositsAppDecisionVO": {
            "decision": "RV",
            "decisionType": "FRD",
            "finalDecision": false,
            "reasonCodes": [
              "DO6001"
            ],
            "rule": false,
            "ruleId": "R1002",
            "ruleName": "WebChk NewCust TotRsk",
            "strategyName": "Web Checking Application Review",
            "weight": 2705
          },
          "depositsApplicantDescnVOs": [
            {
              "applicantDecisionsRuleVOs": [
                {
                  "decision": "AP",
                  "decisionType": "CIP",
                  "finalDecision": false,
                  "reasonCodes": [],
                  "rule": true,
                  "ruleName": "DefaultCIP",
                  "strategyName": "DefaultCIP",
                  "weight": 100
                },
                {
                  "decision": "RV",
                  "decisionType": "FRD",
                  "finalDecision": false,
                  "reasonCodes": [
                    "DO6001"
                  ],
                  "rule": true,
                  "ruleId": "R1002",
                  "ruleName": "WebChk NewCust TotRsk",
                  "strategyName": "Web Checking Application Review",
                  "weight": 2705
                },
                {
                  "decision": "AP",
                  "decisionType": "CIP",
                  "finalDecision": false,
                  "reasonCodes": [],
                  "rule": false,
                  "ruleName": "DefaultCIP",
                  "strategyName": "DefaultCIP",
                  "weight": 100
                },
                {
                  "decision": "RV",
                  "decisionType": "FRD",
                  "finalDecision": false,
                  "reasonCodes": [
                    "DO6001"
                  ],
                  "rule": false,
                  "ruleId": "R1002",
                  "ruleName": "WebChk NewCust TotRsk",
                  "strategyName": "Web Checking Application Review",
                  "weight": 2705
                },
                {
                  "decision": "RV",
                  "decisionType": "FRD",
                  "finalDecision": true,
                  "reasonCodes": [
                    "DO6001"
                  ],
                  "rule": false,
                  "ruleId": "R1002",
                  "ruleName": "WebChk NewCust TotRsk",
                  "strategyName": "Web Checking Application Review",
                  "weight": 2705
                }
              ],
              "applicantModelScoreVOs": [
                {
                  "modelId": "CHEX",
                  "reasonCd": [
                    "AX",
                    "AP",
                    "AD",
                    "AB",
                    null
                  ],
                  "scoreNumber": "0576"
                }
              ],
              "applicantNbr": "DBAPPLCNT5920115",
              "cipPrimVerifySrc": "LNIID",
              "cipVerifyBy": "LexisNexis",
              "cipVerifyMode": "NDOC",
              "strDrvdAttr01": "isMktSrcHghRsk : 1",
              "strDrvdAttr02": "totRskVal : 11",
              "strDrvdAttr03": "isBnkCust : 0",
              "strDrvdAttr04": "bnkCustTen : 0",
              "strDrvdAttr05": "hasChkPrdct : 1",
              "strDrvdAttr06": "isCrdCust : 0",
              "strDrvdAttr07": "newTMXRskVal : 5",
              "strDrvdAttr08": "TMXRskVal : 4",
              "strDrvdAttr09": "newLNFPRskVal : 2",
              "strDrvdAttr10": "LNFPRskVal : 1",
              "strDrvdAttr11": "newEMAGRskVal : 4",
              "strDrvdAttr12": "EMAGRskVal : 4",
              "strDrvdAttr13": "tenureRskVal : 3",
              "strDrvdAttr14": "riskyMrktSrcInd : 1",
              "strDrvdAttr15": "jntOwnInd : 0",
              "strDrvdAttr16": "expL3CallInd : 0",
              "strDrvdAttr17": "lnsFPCallInd : 0",
              "strDrvdAttr18": "hasCDorIRA : 0"
            }
          ],
          "strategyType": "DepositDM"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I was only interested in extracting values of the keys "strDrvdAttr02", "strDrvdAttr04". I have used flatten before for much simpler JSON but this is too complex for me. I was trying to do nested flatten like below but don't think this will work:

```
   WITH DATA2 AS 
   (
                WITH DATA1 AS  
                (
                SELECT
                APLN_ID
                ,parse_json("DMP_OUTP_VAL") AS json
                FROM "SFAAP"."V_SOT_DIRBNK_CRSPRD_FRD_ALL"."VC_EDP_DECSN_LOG"
                WHERE "DMP_CALL_TYP_CDE"='DEPOSITDM'
                AND APLN_ID = 'XXXXXXXXX'
                )
                SELECT 
                APLN_ID
                ,parse_json(f.value) AS mson
                FROM DATA1 d
                ,lateral flatten(input=>d.json) f
   )
   SELECT
   APLN_ID
   ,f.value
   FROM DATA2 d
   ,lateral flatten(input=>d.mson) f
```

I am not able to think of any simpler way to extract those 2 attributes which are kind of sitting in a deeper nested JSON. Hence why looking for taking an expert help. Any comment/help much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
select value:depositsStrategyOutputVOs[0]:depositsApplicantDescnVOs[0]:strDrvdAttr02 , value:depositsStrategyOutputVOs[0]:depositsApplicantDescnVOs[0]:strDrvdAttr04 from( from(
select parse_json('{
  "depositsDMPResponseVO": {
    "depositsApplicationRsnsVO": {
      "applicationID": "YYYYYYY",
      "applicationRefNbr": "XXXXXXXXX",
      "depositsStrategyOutputVOs": [
        {
          "appDescnTms": "2020-08-18T08:07:00Z",
          "depositsAppDecisionVO": {
            "decision": "RV",
            "decisionType": "FRD",
            "finalDecision": false,
            "reasonCodes": [
              "DO6001"
            ],
            "rule": false,
            "ruleId": "R1002",
            "ruleName": "WebChk NewCust TotRsk",
            "strategyName": "Web Checking Application Review",
            "weight": 2705
          },
          "depositsApplicantDescnVOs": [
            {
              "applicantDecisionsRuleVOs": [
                {
                  "decision": "AP",
                  "decisionType": "CIP",
                  "finalDecision": false,
                  "reasonCodes": [],
                  "rule": true,
                  "ruleName": "DefaultCIP",
                  "strategyName": "DefaultCIP",
                  "weight": 100
                },
                {
                  "decision": "RV",
                  "decisionType": "FRD",
                  "finalDecision": false,
                  "reasonCodes": [
                    "DO6001"
                  ],
                  "rule": true,
                  "ruleId": "R1002",
                  "ruleName": "WebChk NewCust TotRsk",
                  "strategyName": "Web Checking Application Review",
                  "weight": 2705
                },
                {
                  "decision": "AP",
                  "decisionType": "CIP",
                  "finalDecision": false,
                  "reasonCodes": [],
                  "rule": false,
                  "ruleName": "DefaultCIP",
                  "strategyName": "DefaultCIP",
                  "weight": 100
                },
                {
                  "decision": "RV",
                  "decisionType": "FRD",
                  "finalDecision": false,
                  "reasonCodes": [
                    "DO6001"
                  ],
                  "rule": false,
                  "ruleId": "R1002",
                  "ruleName": "WebChk NewCust TotRsk",
                  "strategyName": "Web Checking Application Review",
                  "weight": 2705
                },
                {
                  "decision": "RV",
                  "decisionType": "FRD",
                  "finalDecision": true,
                  "reasonCodes": [
                    "DO6001"
                  ],
                  "rule": false,
                  "ruleId": "R1002",
                  "ruleName": "WebChk NewCust TotRsk",
                  "strategyName": "Web Checking Application Review",
                  "weight": 2705
                }
              ],
              "applicantModelScoreVOs": [
                {
                  "modelId": "CHEX",
                  "reasonCd": [
                    "AX",
                    "AP",
                    "AD",
                    "AB",
                    null
                  ],
                  "scoreNumber": "0576"
                }
              ],
              "applicantNbr": "DBAPPLCNT5920115",
              "cipPrimVerifySrc": "LNIID",
              "cipVerifyBy": "LexisNexis",
              "cipVerifyMode": "NDOC",
              "strDrvdAttr01": "isMktSrcHghRsk : 1",
              "strDrvdAttr02": "totRskVal : 11",
              "strDrvdAttr03": "isBnkCust : 0",
              "strDrvdAttr04": "bnkCustTen : 0",
              "strDrvdAttr05": "hasChkPrdct : 1",
              "strDrvdAttr06": "isCrdCust : 0",
              "strDrvdAttr07": "newTMXRskVal : 5",
              "strDrvdAttr08": "TMXRskVal : 4",
              "strDrvdAttr09": "newLNFPRskVal : 2",
              "strDrvdAttr10": "LNFPRskVal : 1",
              "strDrvdAttr11": "newEMAGRskVal : 4",
              "strDrvdAttr12": "EMAGRskVal : 4",
              "strDrvdAttr13": "tenureRskVal : 3",
              "strDrvdAttr14": "riskyMrktSrcInd : 1",
              "strDrvdAttr15": "jntOwnInd : 0",
              "strDrvdAttr16": "expL3CallInd : 0",
              "strDrvdAttr17": "lnsFPCallInd : 0",
              "strDrvdAttr18": "hasCDorIRA : 0"
            }
          ],
          "strategyType": "DepositDM"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}')) as src,
lateral flatten(input => src.$1:depositsDMPResponseVO);
```

Comment: Let me know if that helps.

Comment: This assumes that the order of things inside the arrays are always the same, which might not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have a few unnecessary arrays in there, so you do need the flattens, but you can do that like joins...like this:

```
WITH x AS (
SELECT parse_json('{
  "depositsDMPResponseVO": {
    "depositsApplicationRsnsVO": {
      "applicationID": "YYYYYYY",
      "applicationRefNbr": "XXXXXXXXX",
      "depositsStrategyOutputVOs": [
        {
          "appDescnTms": "2020-08-18T08:07:00Z",
          "depositsAppDecisionVO": {
            "decision": "RV",
            "decisionType": "FRD",
            "finalDecision": false,
            "reasonCodes": [
              "DO6001"
            ],
            "rule": false,
            "ruleId": "R1002",
            "ruleName": "WebChk NewCust TotRsk",
            "strategyName": "Web Checking Application Review",
            "weight": 2705
          },
          "depositsApplicantDescnVOs": [
            {
              "applicantDecisionsRuleVOs": [
                {
                  "decision": "AP",
                  "decisionType": "CIP",
                  "finalDecision": false,
                  "reasonCodes": [],
                  "rule": true,
                  "ruleName": "DefaultCIP",
                  "strategyName": "DefaultCIP",
                  "weight": 100
                },
                {
                  "decision": "RV",
                  "decisionType": "FRD",
                  "finalDecision": false,
                  "reasonCodes": [
                    "DO6001"
                  ],
                  "rule": true,
                  "ruleId": "R1002",
                  "ruleName": "WebChk NewCust TotRsk",
                  "strategyName": "Web Checking Application Review",
                  "weight": 2705
                },
                {
                  "decision": "AP",
                  "decisionType": "CIP",
                  "finalDecision": false,
                  "reasonCodes": [],
                  "rule": false,
                  "ruleName": "DefaultCIP",
                  "strategyName": "DefaultCIP",
                  "weight": 100
                },
                {
                  "decision": "RV",
                  "decisionType": "FRD",
                  "finalDecision": false,
                  "reasonCodes": [
                    "DO6001"
                  ],
                  "rule": false,
                  "ruleId": "R1002",
                  "ruleName": "WebChk NewCust TotRsk",
                  "strategyName": "Web Checking Application Review",
                  "weight": 2705
                },
                {
                  "decision": "RV",
                  "decisionType": "FRD",
                  "finalDecision": true,
                  "reasonCodes": [
                    "DO6001"
                  ],
                  "rule": false,
                  "ruleId": "R1002",
                  "ruleName": "WebChk NewCust TotRsk",
                  "strategyName": "Web Checking Application Review",
                  "weight": 2705
                }
              ],
              "applicantModelScoreVOs": [
                {
                  "modelId": "CHEX",
                  "reasonCd": [
                    "AX",
                    "AP",
                    "AD",
                    "AB",
                    null
                  ],
                  "scoreNumber": "0576"
                }
              ],
              "applicantNbr": "DBAPPLCNT5920115",
              "cipPrimVerifySrc": "LNIID",
              "cipVerifyBy": "LexisNexis",
              "cipVerifyMode": "NDOC",
              "strDrvdAttr01": "isMktSrcHghRsk : 1",
              "strDrvdAttr02": "totRskVal : 11",
              "strDrvdAttr03": "isBnkCust : 0",
              "strDrvdAttr04": "bnkCustTen : 0",
              "strDrvdAttr05": "hasChkPrdct : 1",
              "strDrvdAttr06": "isCrdCust : 0",
              "strDrvdAttr07": "newTMXRskVal : 5",
              "strDrvdAttr08": "TMXRskVal : 4",
              "strDrvdAttr09": "newLNFPRskVal : 2",
              "strDrvdAttr10": "LNFPRskVal : 1",
              "strDrvdAttr11": "newEMAGRskVal : 4",
              "strDrvdAttr12": "EMAGRskVal : 4",
              "strDrvdAttr13": "tenureRskVal : 3",
              "strDrvdAttr14": "riskyMrktSrcInd : 1",
              "strDrvdAttr15": "jntOwnInd : 0",
              "strDrvdAttr16": "expL3CallInd : 0",
              "strDrvdAttr17": "lnsFPCallInd : 0",
              "strDrvdAttr18": "hasCDorIRA : 0"
            }
          ],
          "strategyType": "DepositDM"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}') as payload_json)
    select f2.value:strDrvdAttr02::varchar,
           f2.value:strDrvdAttr03::varchar
    from x,
    lateral flatten(input => x.payload_json:depositsDMPResponseVO:depositsApplicationRsnsVO:depositsStrategyOutputVOs) f,
    lateral flatten(input => f.value:depositsApplicantDescnVOs) f2;
```